# compiling ragel on mavericks

Tags: osx-mavericks, ios7.1, libvlc, ragel

I have downloaded ragel source code and trying to compile it.

I am not able to configure it. getting following error on running

./configure --prefix=PREFIX

-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

I have download all necessary command line compilation tools. not sure what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much easier to use [MacPorts](http://macports.org).  So after [installation](https://www.macports.org/install.php):

```
$ sudo port install ragel
```

and it will take care of downloading dependencies, and will already know how to configure the project.